# Problema Codigo UPDATE MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Alguem poderia me confirmar se o codigo abaixo está correto, eu não sou bom em php nem em mysql, só faço arranjos e não estou conseguindo o resultado esperado, a conexão com db está correta, não apresenta erros(exite um if para error)...

O resultado esperado é quando preencher no html "name" seja inserido 100000 na columa paymoney WHERE name=name

full code http://pastebin.com/Y65ThtnK

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

include_once 'dbcon.php';

if(isset($_POST['btn-signup'])) {

 $name = trim($_POST['name']);



 $name = strip_tags($name);



 // paymoney encrypt using SHA256();


 // check usuario dup
 $query = "UPDATE player SET paymoney='10000'
           WHERE name ='$name'";


}
?>
```

Comment: Poderia dar mais detalhes e mencionar de que tipo é esse valor 100000 pois se ele for do tipo int você não precisa usar aspas simples e a variável nome tente passar assim '".$name."'.

Comment: Só falta executar a consulta no banco.

Answer (score 2):

Falta executar.

```
$query = "UPDATE player SET paymoney='10000'
           WHERE name ='$name'";
$suaconexao -> query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloque a sql assim:

```
$query = "UPDATE player SET paymoney='10000'
           WHERE name = ".$name;
```